# Is this the best way to determine that a List of ints contains a 0?

Tags: c#

Is this the best way to determine that the `List<int> ALogMsgTypeIntArray` contains a 0?

```
if (ALogMsgTypeIntArray.Exists(delegate(int i) { return i == 0; }))
{
    MessageBox.Show("0 exists");
}
```

==========
Updated:

I ended up doing it this-a-way:

```
bGetDebug = ALogMsgTypeIntList.Contains(LogParsePumpViewerConsts.LOG_MSG_TYPE_DEBUG);
bGetInfo = ALogMsgTypeIntList.Contains(LogParsePumpViewerConsts.LOG_MSG_TYPE_INFORMATION);
bGetWarning = ALogMsgTypeIntList.Contains(LogParsePumpViewerConsts.LOG_MSG_TYPE_WARNING);
bGetError = ALogMsgTypeIntList.Contains(LogParsePumpViewerConsts.LOG_MSG_TYPE_ERROR);
```

Comment: You should name your `List<int>` as `…IntList`, not `…IntArray`, since this might confuse other developers on how to use your variable. An int array would be `int[]`.

Comment: @Douglas: This applies not only for other developers ;)

Comment: It's a bit ironic how the question title contains the name of the method you should use.

Comment: Thanks; it was originally an int array, and I forgot to change the name.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Good point. It got _me_ confused because I was sure that arrays don’t have an `Exists` instance/extension method.

Comment: @Douglas: Your suggestion is *better* but still not great. **Names should not contain a description of the type mechanism at all** and **should not contain abbrvtns** The proper name for this thing is something like `MessageTypes`. The constants should be something like `LogParsePumpViewerType.Debug`, not `LogParsePumpViewerConsts.LOG_MSG_TYPE_DEBUG`. Locals should not be prefixed with "Hungarian" style prefixes; use `getDebug`, not `bGetDebug`. Read the Framework Design Guidelines for lots of good advice on how to follow best practices for naming things.

Comment: Also, consider using lambdas rather than anonymous methods if you are going to use `Exists`. `if(LogMessageTypes.Exists(i=>i==0))` is much more concise.

Comment: @EricLippert: In the general case, I agree. (When I posted my comment, there wasn’t the update providing contextual information on the list’s intended use.) But I wouldn’t hold either of your statements as categorical. The .NET FCL is littered with abbreviations: `Db`, `Id`, `Func`…

Comment: @Douglas: I take your point. But the fact that some people violated the guidelines in the past is not a good reason to do so in new code.

Comment: @Douglas: `Db` is considered an acronym and is okay by the design guidelines. `Id` is considered one of the acceptable abbreviations (the other is `Ok`). Both of these are explicitly spelled out.

Comment: @Jason The guidelines are incorrect about "db" -- it's not an acronym *under the guidelines' own definition of acronym*, as "database" is one word.  (I would also argue that "OK" is not an abbreviation, but no matter.)

Comment: @EricLippert given that the guidelines are "guidelines" and not "style *rules*", it's not surprising that they have been violated in some cases.  (And after additional research since the last comment, I am even more certain that "db" *is* an abbreviation and "ok" is *not*)

Comment: @phoog: I would not personally use "Db". There are other interesting corner cases for naming as well: for example, System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.  On the one hand, the guidelines say not to put capital letters next to each other. On the other hand, no one wants to slight Shamir and Adleman. Politeness, in this case, won.

Comment: Interestingly, when I was researching .NET naming conventions for constants to prove my colleague, that using ALL_CAPS is discouraged, I couldn't find any official Microsoft guideline to support my point. There is default StyleCop rule for that, but it's hardly official.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [List<T>.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx):

```
if (ALogMsgTypeIntArray.Contains(0))
{
    MessageBox.Show("0 exists");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your criteria for "best".  If "shortest source code" is your primary goal, then the answer is no:

```
if (ALogMsgTypeIntArray.Exists(i => i == 0) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("0 exists"); 
}
```

Comment: For the OP's benefit, I'd point out that `i => i == 0` is just shorthand for `delegate(int i) { return i == 0; }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALogMsgTypeIntArray.Any(item => item == 0)
```

is what I'd use

Comment: No joke, your avatar looks strikingly like (a caricature of, of course) my oldest son (he's 28).